# Which is the better framework to build a HTML survey builder?

Tags: webforms, frameworks, survey

I’ve to build a HTML survey builder application with an AJAXified user interface (i.e.*Wufoo*,...).

The typical survey will be multistep with multi-dependencies between form fields/questions, public access most of the time, and export results to PDF + CSV.

Have been studying/testing some PHP frameworks ( CodeIgniter, Symfony and CakePHP).
I like CakePHP, but I read a lot of good stuff about Django and RoR (especially RoR for form building...)...

...so the question: which is the better framework to build a HTML survey builder?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say all the frameworks you mention are a good fit for such an application. So the question mainly becomes: Which is your set of expertise? If you are very proficient in PHP and haven't ever seen Ruby or Python, then one of the PHP ones is certainly a better fit if you wish rapid development.

I'd stick with the framework I like written in the language I know best.

Also, in my experience it's best to avoid RoR's scaffolding (automatic form creation) when you'll be doing variable length autogenerated forms. You can take a look on [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) for more info about that and how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion is that Zend Framework is the best in cases like this one. It's very modular and it also provides nice export components.

You would probably be interested in Zend Ajax and Zend_Pdf components. You can also use most of them as standalone classes.

You can find a list and documentation with examples of all Zend Frameworks components [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/).